# I have a method which only needs to be executed once in PHP but will be called twice. How do I structure this?

Tags: php

I have a method in PHP which calls a SOAP service, parses some data and returns it.

It will return the same data - it asks how many records in a data object.

I need to call it twice with a pass.

My question is, what is best practice for structuring this in PHP? I've tried to see if the function has been called already.Do I use static variables / functions?

```
function MinimumRequired() { 
        return $this->NumberPeopleJoined();
    }   

function NumberPeopleJoined () {
        if (isset($NumberPeople)) {
            Debug::Show($NumberPeople);
        }
        static $NumberPeople;
        $NumberPeople = Surge_Controller::NumberPeopleJoined();
        return $NumberPeople;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just create a **local** class member, and check if that has a value. If not, set the value to whatever is retrieved from `Surge_Controller`, and if it was already set, just return the value:

```
<?php

class Surge_Controller {
    static public function NumberPeopleJoined() {
        echo "Surge_Controller::NumberPeopleJoined() got called.\n";
        return 2;
    }
}

class Foo {
    protected $cacheNumberPeople;

    function MinimumRequired() { 
        return $this->NumberPeopleJoined();
    }   

    function NumberPeopleJoined () {
        if( !isset( $this->cacheNumberPeople ) ) {
            $this->cacheNumberPeople = Surge_Controller::NumberPeopleJoined();
        }
        return $this->cacheNumberPeople;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo( );
echo $foo->numberPeopleJoined( ) . "\n";
echo $foo->numberPeopleJoined( ) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
$ php foo.php
Surge_Controller::NumberPeopleJoined() got called.
2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to have a global variable, and check if is "true", and set it to true at the end of your function. The value can be cached too...

But if you want to make your code fun, you can use underscore:
http://brianhaveri.github.com/Underscore.php/#once
http://brianhaveri.github.com/Underscore.php/#memoize